What is the $\inf$ and $\sup$ of the area of quadrilateral given its sides length?
Now asked on MO here.

Given the length of the sides of a quadrilateral $a,b,c,d$ the area of the quadrilateral is less than or equal to $\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{16}$ i.e it is an upper bound of the area of  any quadrilateral  with side length $a,b,c,d$.
A question that came to my mind is if $\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{16}$ is an upper bound Then the least upper bound exits so what is the infimum  and supremum of the area of quadrilateral (0 is an oblivious lower bound so the infimum   exists too)?
I made a silly mistake thinking that $\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{16}$ is the supremum but it turns out I was wrong.
If $a=b, \ c=d$ "a kite" or if $a=c, \   d=b$ "a parallelogram" then it is easy to prove the infimum  is $0$ and the supremum  is just $a^2$ when it is a rhombus.

The infimum  depends on $a,b,c,d$ in this examples the side lengths are $19,13,7,4$ and the minimum area is around $9.5$ so it is not $0$.

Conjecture: If $a<b<c<d$ and the area of the quadrilateral  is $S$ then $\inf S $ is the area of the triangle $a,b,d-c$ which is
$$\sqrt{\frac{a+b+d-c}{2}\cdot\frac{a-b+d-c}{2}\cdot\frac{-a+b+d-c}{2}\cdot\frac{a+b-d+c}{2}}$$ This also works when $a=b=c=d, \ \ \ a=b, \ c=d \ \ \  ,a=c, \ d=b $.
I couldn't rigorously proof that claim but I am pretty sure it is correct.

In the previous example when side lengths are $19,13,7,4$ the naximum area is around $73.5$ but this time I have no Idea what kind of shape is that.


How to determine  the infimum and the supremum  of the area given $a,b,c,d$.

May we assume that the side lengths are given in order around the quadrilateral?

It might depend on the values of $a,b,c,d$ but in general you can make some of the angels as small as possible and the others as close to $180$.  But we could have some issues.  If $b=d < c <a$ but $c+b >a$ we can't lay any two sides flat.

Let three sides be $1$  and the last edge $0.0001$  Draw some pictures

@WillJagy That should probably be an answer (with perhaps one more sentence). :)

I could be wrong be I don't the $\frac {(a+b+d)^2}{16}$ is the least upper bound of all quads.  I believe it is an upper bound of all quads and for some values of $a,b,c,d$ is is the least upper bound but there are some values of $a,b,c,d$ where the least upper bound is quite smaller.  Likewise there are some values of $a,b,c,$ were $0$ is the greatest lowerbound (rhombuses for ex) but there are some where it not (trapezoids for example).  I think if $b=c; a<d$ then the $\sup < \frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{16}$ and $\inf > 0$.

@fleablood You are correct I made a silly mistake thinking that any quadrilateral   could be square even without equal side length

@WillJagy  Note also, in your example the area (which is roughly that an equilateral triangle $\approx \frac{\sqrt{3}}4$ is a lot less than $\frac {(1+1+1+0.0001)^2}{16}$.  So neither $0$ is the greatest lower bound (of all) nor is $\frac {(a+b+c+d)^2}{16}$ the least upper bound (of all).

Take a parellegram with sides $1,1$ and $10,10$.  It's area will but $\sin \theta\cdot 10$ where $\theta$ is the base angle.  The sup is when it is a rectangle with area $10$.  However ${(10+1+1+10)^2}{16} =30.25$.  So $\frac{(a+b+c+d)}{16}$ is the sup of all quads or all values of sides but not of any particular set of sides. Likewise $0$ is the inf of all of all possible but not of any particular set of sides.  So... I'd say if you can make your first claim you can make you second and be done with... but they are a universal upper and lower and not, in some cases, sup or inf.

I think.  That sup is $\frac {a+b+c+d)^2}{16}$ only if the quad is a rhombus (max area acheived as square), and I think the inf is $0$ only if the quad is a parallelegram (min area acheived as a squashed box)

@fleablood Non-parallelograms can be flattened as well; eg any kite $a,a,b,b$ can be flattened. 4,3,2,1 is another example -- I think $a,b,c,b+c-a$ gives a family of things that can be flattened.

Areas can get arbitrarily small under some circumstances,  suach as edges (in order) $a,b,a,b$  which has maximal area as a rectangle,  but can be squashed down as a parallelogram.
The example that came to mind was, essentially, an equilateral triangle.  Let three edges  have length $100$  but the final edge have length $1.$  From what I can see, the least area is when the $1$  lies flat against a neighboring edge, nonconvex, resulting triangle edges $100, 100, 99$
My first guess on the maximum area is isosceles triangle with sides $100, 100, 101$
triangle $100, 100, 99$   came out  4301.02.  triangle $100, 100, 101$   came out  4358.75.
The cyclic quadrilateral $100,100, 100, 1$  comes out 4387.9095.

The greatest area will be when the length 1 side is close to perpendicular to form a quadrilateral. The closer you can get to a circle, the greater the enclosed area.  4380 vs 4360 for the triangle.

The supremum will be when the four nodes lie exactly on a circle: a cyclic quadrilateral. The area of a quadrilateral inscribed in a circle is given by Bretschneider’s formula (actually Brahmagupta's formula) as:Brahmagupta
Area = √[(s-a) (s-b) (s – c) (s – d)]  where s is the semi-perimeter of the quadrilateral $\frac {a+b+c+d}{2}$
Your original for maximum area provides an example of this:
EDIT: Proof
Bretschneider’s formula gives the area for any quadrilateral from lengths of sides:
Area $$ \sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)-abcd*cos^2((\alpha+\gamma)/2)} $$
where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are either pair of opposite angles in the quadrilateral.
a,b,c and d are all positive, $cos^2$ is always positive, therefore this will be a maximum when $cos^2$ = 0, i.e. when shape is cyclic quadrilateral. QED
The smallest area will occur when the $cos^2$ term is as large as possible (1). This happens when the quadrilateral is flattened and those angles will be 0+0 or $\pi$ + $\pi$.
If the quadrilateral cannot be flattened then a triangle will remain. If we label the sides a,b,c, and d then let c lie collinear with d. The angle between c and d is then 0.  c and d are chosen such that the angle between the other two sides, a and b is the smallest of the possible choices. Increasing the angle between c and d also increases the angle between a and b increasing the area, so this is the minimum.
Apologies - the first site I linked to had errors.

This is a very good observation, It remains to prove these two calims.

@pie First one down

@pie My other assumption was not correct. I have edited it out
